# Android Radio Button Not selected giving error

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a Android Radio button, i need to display the error message if the Radio button is not selected. Hence i included the below Java code, but its giving the below error.

Logcat ERROR:

```
07-12 16:00:08.139: E/AndroidRuntime(8282): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-12 16:00:08.149: E/AndroidRuntime(8282): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 16:00:08.149: E/AndroidRuntime(8282):     at com.example.triviality.QuizActivity$1.onClick(QuizActivity.java:67)
```

In the 67th Line the below sentence is there

```
      String answerval = (String) answer.getText();
```

Please find the Partial Java Code:

```
butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                    RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                    String answerval = (String) answer.getText();               
                    if (answerval == "")
                    {   
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuizActivity.this);
                        alertDialog.setTitle(" ");
                        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.wrong);
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Please select one Option"); 
                        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                            }                   
                            });
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: your findViewById code must be outside and before setOnClickListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to display error message when no `RadioButton` are selected.

If that's the case then `grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` will return `-1` and hence `answer` will be `null`.

Then if you try to do `answer.getText()` you will get a `NullPointerException` because you are caling `getText` on a null object.

**EDIT:**

Replace

```
RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
String answerval = (String) answer.getText();               
if (answerval == "")
```

with

```
if(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1)
```